# How can I use 2 providers in the same terraform config?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

My main.tf file starts with

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.13.7"
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "= 2.32.0"
    }
    foobar = {
      source = "terraform.foo.com/foo/bar"
    }
  }
}
```

The catch here is that **foo/bar** is the module I'm developing locally so I also has this terraformrc file:

```
provider_installation {
  dev_overrides {
    "terraform.foo.com/foo/bar" = "/Users/appuser/foobar/bin/darwin-amd64"
  }
}
```

Here's the errors I run into when running `✗ terraform init`

```
Initializing the backend...

Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding hashicorp/aws versions matching "2.32.0"...
- Finding latest version of terraform.foo.com/foo/bar...

Warning: Provider development overrides are in effect

The following provider development overrides are set in the CLI configuration:
 - "terraform.foo.com/foo/bar" = "/Users/appuser/foobar/bin/darwin-amd64"

Error: Failed to query available provider packages

Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/aws:
no available releases match the given constraints 2.32.0


Error: Failed to query available provider packages

Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider
"terraform.foo.com/foo/bar": no available releases
match the given constraints
```

Update: when I remove terraformrc it does seem to work but I am not able to load the 2nd provider this way (since it relies on override):

```
terraform init

Initializing the backend...

Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding hashicorp/aws versions matching "2.32.0"...
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/foo/bar...
- Installing hashicorp/aws v2.32.0...
- Installed hashicorp/aws v2.32.0 (self-signed, key ID 34365D9472D7468F)

Partner and community providers are signed by their developers.
If you'd like to know more about provider signing, you can read about it here:
https://www.terraform.io/docs/plugins/signing.html

Error: Failed to query available provider packages

Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider
hashicorp/foo/bar: provider registry registry.terraform.io does not
have a provider named registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/foo/bar
```

Comment: This is unrelated to the number of providers in the config. The version constrains for the AWS provider need to be fixed, and the custom provider is likely completely missing a version. Give that a try.

Comment: well it does work if I remove the 2nd provider and remove terraformrc file (i.e., see my edit above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dev_overrides` setting is, in spite of being placed inside the `provider_installation` block due to its thematic similarity, actually a *runtime* setting rather than an installation setting. Specifically, it asks Terraform to ignore whatever version of the provider `terraform init` previously selected and to use the given overridden provider instead.

Unfortunately, this model only works well if you're overriding a provider that already has at least one published version available, so that `terraform init` can select and install that version but then `terraform apply` (for example) can then ignore what `terraform init` installed, and use the override instead. (Terraform behaves this way because part of `terraform init`'s responsibility is to update [the Dependency Lock File](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/dependency-lock.html), and so it needs to find at least one selectable version of each provider in order to produce a complete lock file.)

One way you could avoid this design quirk is to place a fake "release" of this provider in a local directory that you'd then configure as a filesystem mirror for that provider, in your `.terraformrc` file.

For example, if you create a directory `/tmp/tf-workaround/terraform.foo.com/foo/bar/0.0.1/darwin_amd64` and place into it an empty file named `terraform-provider-bar` then that should be sufficient for `terraform init` to detect this as an available "published" version of the provider if given an CLI configuration like this:

```
provider_installation {
  dev_overrides {
    "terraform.foo.com/foo/bar" = "/Users/appuser/foobar/bin/darwin-amd64"
  }

  filesystem_mirror {
    path    = "/tmp/tf-workaround"
    include = ["terraform.foo.com/foo/bar"]
  }

  direct {
    exclude = ["terraform.foo.com/foo/bar"]
  }
}
```

`terraform init` should then find the placeholder empty file and "install" it into `.terraform/providers` as normal. That empty file won't actually work as a valid plugin, but that's okay because `terraform apply` will ignore it anyway and will use the directory given in `dev_overrides` instead.

However, the dependency lock file will contain an incorrect entry for `terraform.foo.com/foo/bar` after installation, so if you intend to commit this test configuration to version control then you may wish to manually remove that block to reduce confusion once there really is a release of this provider.

The less-complex way to work here is to test a provider during development with a configuration that *only* includes that provider, and wait until you've actually published the provider somewhere before you use it "for real" as part of a larger system. In that case, you'd typically skip running `terraform init` altogether because the only external dependency would be the overridden provider, and so nothing additional would need to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

The fix (which was to add `direct {}`) was found in TF [docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/config/config-file.html#provider-installation):

```
provider_installation {

  # Use /home/developer/tmp/terraform-null as an overridden package directory
  # for the hashicorp/null provider. This disables the version and checksum
  # verifications for this provider and forces Terraform to look for the
  # null provider plugin in the given directory.
  dev_overrides {
    "hashicorp/null" = "/home/developer/tmp/terraform-null"
  }

  # For all other providers, install them directly from their origin provider
  # registries as normal. If you omit this, Terraform will _only_ use
  # the dev_overrides block, and so no other providers will be available.
  direct {}
}
```

Actually I'm still getting

```
Error: Failed to query available provider packages

Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider
hashicorp/foo/bar: could not connect to hashicorp: Failed
to request discovery document: Get
"https://hashicorp/.well-known/terraform.json": dial tcp: lookup hashicorp on
100.217.9.1:53: no such host
```